# Dynamic drop down menus

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, drop-down-menu

I want to create a dynamic drop down where the options of the second drop down changes after the selection of the first drop down.

The test.php file

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","******","****","******");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM countries");
?>
<select id="country" name='country' onchange="get_states();">
<option value=''>Select</option>
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<option value='" . $row['country_id'] . "'>" . $row['country_name'] . "</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<div id="get_state"></div> // Sub will be appended here using ajax

<script type="text/javascript">
function get_states() { // Call to ajax function
var country = $('#country').val();
var dataString = "country="+country;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getstates.php", // Name of the php files
    data: dataString,
    success: function(html)
    {
        $("#get_state").html(html);
    }
});
}
</script>
<?php
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

and the gestates.php is:

```
<?php if ($_POST) {
$country = $_POST['country'];
if ($country != '') {
   $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM states WHERE country_id=" . $country;
   $result1 = mysql_query($sql1);
   echo "<select name='state'>";
   echo "<option value=''>Select</option>"; 
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
      echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['state_name'] . "</option>";}
   echo "</select>";
}
else
{
    echo  '';
}
}
?>
```

However the above code does not work!

Comment: exactly what error you got???

Comment: there is no error. [link](http://www.crazypencilmedia.com/demos/test-1.php)

Answer (score 0):

on change on first drop-down you need to make an ajax call which will get the options and you can then populate the next drop-down

Answer (score 0):

Try adding single quotes around $country

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM states WHERE country_id='" . $country . "'";

or

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM states WHERE country_id='$country'";

**EDIT:**  Also, you can only echo one result.  Your second echo will be ignored by Jquery as the first will be considered a success.

You should format your results differently.

Perhaps a json encoded array.

In your php:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
      $data[$row['id']] = $row['state_name'];
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

In your Jquery set dataType: 'json'

```
$.each(html,function(key,value){

      $("#get_state").append($('<option>',{ 
               value:key,
           text: value
    }));
});
```